# dbt- synapse models\example generating error

Tags: azure-synapse, dbt

The problem I’m having is after the profiles.yml All checks passed! (the connection successful)
when i run dbt get this message

```
Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources. There are 1 unused configuration paths:- models.dbt_project.example
```

when I run

```
dbt --version
Core:  - installed: 1.4.1
  - latest:    1.4.1 - Up to date!
Plugins:  - sqlserver: 1.3.0 - Not compatible!
  - synapse:   1.3.2 - Not compatible!
  At least one plugin is out of date or incompatible with dbt-core.
  You can find instructions for upgrading here:
  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/installation
```

Comment: here is the setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you what is wrong. There is config in your `dbt_project.yml` file that does not apply to any files in your `models` directory.

When you run `dbt init`, it creates some example models (.sql files) in the `models/example` directory, like `my_first_dbt_model.sql`. It also adds some example config to `dbt_project.yml` that looks like this:

```yaml
# towards the bottom...
models:
  your_project_name:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

You need to delete the `example` key, since you deleted that directory. You could also delete the keys above it, or keep them, since you'll probably add config at some point.

The OTHER error is probably because you installed `dbt-core` separately from `dbt-synapse`. You should delete your virtual environment and start over by just running `pip install dbt-synapse`, which will automatically install a compatible version of `dbt-core`. You should NEVER pin versions of `dbt-core`, only the version of your adapter (since the adapter will specify its compatible versions of `dbt-core`).