# There are 1 unused configuration paths

Tags: azure-synapse, dbt

(dbt-env) C:\dbt_project>dbt compile
20:21:56  Running with dbt=1.3.1
20:21:56  [WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
**There are 1 unused configuration paths:**

- models.dbt_project.example

20:21:56  Found 0 models, 0 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 339 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 0 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics
20:21:56
20:21:56  [WARNING]: Nothing to do. Try checking your model configs and model specification args
20:21:56  Done.

and the adapter is dby-synapse

> ---
>
> dbt_project.yml
>
> name: 'dbt_project'
> version: '1.0.0'
> config-version: 2
>
> profile: 'dbt_project'
>
> model-paths: ["models"]
> analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
> test-paths: ["tests"]
> seed-paths: ["seeds"]
> macro-paths: ["macros"]
> snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]
>
> target-path: "target"
> clean-targets:
> - "target"
> - "dbt_packages"
>
> models:
> dbt_project:
> example:
> +materialized: view
>
> ---

> dbt init dbt_projct...
>
> Note:  dbt debug.. all is successful
>
> Configuration:
> profiles.yml file [OK found and valid]
> dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]
>
> Required dependencies:
> git [OK found]
>
> Connection test: [OK connection ok]
>
> All checks passed!
>
> when compiling or run get the error

Comment: Please I need help in this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dbt- synapse models\example generating error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260058/dbt-synapse-models-example-generating-error)

Answer (score 0):

My case was folder issue.. i was running the dbt from wrong folder